# No onchange event in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My HTML has an input element like

```
<input contenteditable="true" onkeydown="stopKey(event,[13,27])" onchange="relay(event)" type="text">
```

(I've left out the style attribute).
When I enter some data and leave the element with a TAB, Chrome will call the relay function when the page is loaded from a webserver. But it will not call relay when the page is loaded locally from localhost. The same difference in behaviour when I leave the element by clicking on another element. Only when leaving it with the ENTER key will the event be triggered in both situations.
I have made sure that the page, css, javascript are exactly the same. I compare the two pages in different tabs of the same Chrome browser. There is no such problem in IE. The site has been working for years, but always from a remote server. I would like to know if this can be explained and if it can be repaired.

Comment: contenteditable doesn't have onchange event. **Edit** input doesn't have contenteditable attribute

Answer (score 0):

If the page will be used on a server then always test it that way. Life is too short to examine all the causes of local and remote differences in behaviour.